# can't install rails on new mint os load error openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux-mint

**September 3rd Updated**

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

libssl-dev already the newest version.

but still getting the same error.

```
 root@Lintong:~# gem install rails
    ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- openssl
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
        undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I installed ruby by compiling I did not use rvm. I asked how to install ruby on mint without using rvm here

[installed ruby using apt-get install ruby 2.0.0 succeeded but not using correct ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541695/installed-ruby-using-apt-get-install-ruby-2-0-0-succeeded-but-not-using-correct/18541768?noredirect=1#comment27275498_18541768)

now when I do gem install rails I got the above error, what dependencies am I missing? I don't usually use linux for development. I am doing this for the first time because I am deploying to a vps (digital ocean)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `libssl-dev` package. Try installing that package and recompiling Ruby. You may be missing other packages as well.

Comment: I installed the package with apt-get install but I am still getting the same error shouldn't this go away and be replaced with another dependency that I need? I mean I recompiled it ./configure make

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to debug server config issues without seeing the server itself. In my experience, installing that package has made that error disappear.